# How can I make a money box to work. ( JavaScript )

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I start to make projects where help me to learn better the code language. I'm stuck somewhere and I need your help. I made a money box where i can put money inside also i can bring it out. Now I'm trying to do it.

If the amount I put for a subtraction is greater than what I have insite, don't remove it and gives you a note and it also doesn't stop at zero.

I did but it doesn't work.

How can I do that?

**My HTML**

```
  <!-- logo start-->
    <div class="logo">Money Box</div>
    <!-- logo end-->

    <!-- money box start -->
    <div class="form">
      <input type="number" class="money" /><br />
      <button type="submit" class="addition">+</button>
      <button type="submit" class="subtraction">-</button>
    </div>
    <div class="total--0" value="0">0</div>
    <div class="minus"></div>
    <!-- money box end -->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
"use strict";

const addition = document.querySelector(".addition");
const subtraction = document.querySelector(".subtraction");
let total = document.querySelector(".total--0");
const minus = document.querySelector(".minus");
const amount = document.querySelector(".money");

let sum = 0;
total = sum;
// console.log(total == 0);


//Add btn number
document.querySelector(".addition").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const writeMoney = Number(amount.value);

  minus.textContent = "";

  if (writeMoney) {
    amount.value = "";
    let mon = (sum += writeMoney);
    document.querySelector(".total--0").textContent = `$ ${mon}`;

  } else if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) {
    minus.textContent = "Invalid amount. Please enter a positive number.";
  }
});


//Remove btn number
subtraction.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const writeMoney = Number(amount.value);
  minus.textContent = "";

  if (writeMoney) {
    amount.value = "";
    let mon = (sum -= writeMoney);
    document.querySelector(".total--0").textContent = `$ ${mon}`;

  } else if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 0) {
    minus.textContent = "Invalid amount. Please enter a positive number.";

  } else if (writeMoney > total) {
    document.querySelector(".total").textContent = `You don't have that much money in your wallet`;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check the condition for overdrawing first, as none of the `else` branches are checked after the first true condition.

```js
if (writeMoney > sum) {
    minus.textContent = `You don't have that much money in your wallet`;
} else if (writeMoney) {
// ...
```

Additional notes:

- Compare with `sum`, not `total`, which is never changed after being set to `0`.
- The condition `amount < 0` does not make sense, as `amount` is an input element. You should compare with `amount.value` or `amount.valueAsNumber`. In this case, you already have the value stored in the variable `writeMoney`, so use that.